# Line breaks being removed from email body

Tags: c#, outlook, gmail, newline, stringbuilder

I'm generating a simple email using the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class and building the body with a `StringBuilder`. I'm looping through a `string[]` and trying to append a new line each time. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to generate a single new line each time. I can either get two or none.

**What I've tried:**

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    body.AppendLine(message);
}

foreach (var message in messages)
{
    body.Append(message + "\n");
}

foreach (var message in messages)
{
    body.Append(message + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I've also tried with `string.Format()`.

For each example above, I get the same result. No new line being generated.

When I try the following, however, I get the expected result. A new line with an empty line in between.

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    body.AppendLine(message + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Why is it doing this and what can I do to just get a single new line each time?

**Update:**

So I've found that Outlook and probably Gmail (haven't tested others) are actually removing some line breaks and not others. Does anyone know why or how they determine what to remove?

[image]

Comment: Why you think that new lines not added?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Everything shows on the same line.

Comment: In your working example, you are appending a line with a line break.  In the one that doesn't, you are only using Append with only one line break.  It's not clear to me the issue you are having.

Comment: @EliArbel It's not html

Comment: @LarsTech I think you misunderstand, the "working" example appends two lines, as I'm using appendline and newline. The other examples I think should append one but I do not get a newline in the email.

Comment: What returns  `body.ToString().Split('\n').Length`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Good question. Just ran it and it does register the newline on split, I'm just not seeing the result for some reason.

Comment: How do you confirm that no new lines are added? Is it in mail client? You said that _it's not html_ but maybe mail client treats it as such.

Comment: Just show the result of expression in consloe/output/messsagebox. What you mean by `it does register the newline on split`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I mean it does split where the newlines are added, what exactly are you asking? It returns one greater than the length of my string[]...

Comment: @dkozl I explicitly set IsBodyHtml to false, also why does my last example with two new lines work?

Comment: Ok, then you have one string delimited by newlines.

Comment: Outlook and some other email clients have a tendency to remove line breaks thinking they are extra. Have you tried viewing in another email client?

Comment: @justinlabenne Nice thought but no I sent it to my gmail and get the same thing.

Comment: Add your code that sends the email, along with smtp Web.config settings if exists.

Comment: Try setting email format to html and use <br /> for the line breaks

Comment: I second the "add more code" comment, and also, can you check the properties of the email and ensure that they are "Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8". I cannot replicate the problem if IsBodyHtml=false.

Comment: @BateTech I agree that will work, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I will check the properties and update, hold on.

Comment: What happens if you use "\r\n" instead of just "\n" ? http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?144973-Plain-text-email-line-breaks-not-working&s=330b6fb743c622abcc139873e2f4e793&p=745552#post745552

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I checked the email in Outlook, I got a tiny info message saying "Extra line breaks in this message were removed" and the option to restore them. Gmail gave no such indication (that I found) but I must assume it removed them as well.

Interestingly enough I had line breaks elsewhere in the body that worked as expected, only the ones in the loop were deemed "extra".

I have modified my code to build the email body using html.

```
IsBodyHtml = true
```

If anyone knows of a way to prevent this, or what causes certain line breaks to be removed, please let me know.

**Update:**

Once I knew what I was looking for, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247546/outlook-autocleaning-my-line-breaks-and-screwing-up-my-email-format?rq=1) post which helps to explain things and gives some alternate solutions. I did not try any of them, as I think using html is the better solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail will remove explicit line breaks. This code works for me when sending to Gmail, as well as Outlook with proper line breaks intact. I am completely unable to replicate your issue without seeing what your messages[] array looks like. It may be possible that some formatting could be viewed as line breaks causing all to be stripped out? I have tampered with my example strings and I cannot get Outlook nor Gmail to strip the line breaks on me.

```
    private void SendMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            string[] messages = { "test with    a tab in it", "    test with     spaces", " \r\nTab, then line break", "\n\n\n\n\n\nlots of returns...", "                test spaces" };

            foreach (var msg in messages)
            {
                body.AppendLine(msg);
                //body.AppendLine(string.Empty);
            }


            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress("you@test.com", "Your Display Name");
                message.ReplyToList.Add("reply-email@test.com");
                message.To.Add("to@test.com");
                message.Subject = "Test Line Break Message";
                message.IsBodyHtml = false;
                message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Body = body.ToString();

                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtpClient.Host = "127.0.0.1";
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am going to assume somewhere in your code that builds or retrieves the messages array, something is happening to cause this issue. I would believe it to be fixable, but not without seeing how that part is coded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this actually adds an extra empty line though. In my question, you can see I was able to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran this through LINQPad

```
string[] messages = new string[]{"First line in message", "Second Line in message", "Third Line in message"};

StringBuilder sbA = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbB = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbC = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbD = new StringBuilder();

// New line for each string
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    sbA.AppendLine(message);
}

// New line for each string
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    sbB.Append(message + "\n");
}

// New line for each string
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    sbC.Append(message + System.Environment.NewLine);
}

//One Line
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    sbD.Append(message);
}


sbA.Dump();
sbB.Dump();
sbC.Dump();
sbD.Dump();
```

Each one performs as expected in a StringBuilder sense.

I suspect that you need to add `"</br>"` at the end of each AppendLine something like this (not tested):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("someSender@email.com"), new MailAddress("someReceiver@email.com"));
string[] messages = new string[]{"First line in message", "Second Line in message", "Third Line in message"};

StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

body.AppendLine("<h2>My Message<h2></br>" );

foreach (var message in messages)
{
    body.AppendLine(message + "</br>");
}

mail.Body = body.ToString();

mail.Dump();
```

Comment: See the answer I posted. You're right, the StringBuilder works as expected. Originally, I was not using html in the message but when I do adding </br> does in fact work.