# How do I properly print a multi-line variable in an e-mail sent from a BASH script?

Tags: bash, email, sendmail, netcat

I have a BASH script that runs various sysadmin functions and system checks. If a check fails, a variable is set to `1`. There are only a couple types of errors that can happen, so I have variables named to describe the error such as `$login_error` and `$timeout`.

At the end of the script, if an error was encountered, an e-mail is sent to my team. In the e-mail, I include a brief error message describing what the error was. The problem I'm getting is that the error messages contain a `\n` character, but my embedded e-mail doesn't preserve the newlines.

I'll show you what I mean. Here's the function that checks for failures and e-mails me:

```
checkFailure () {
    if [[ $error_encountered -eq 1 ]]; then

    [[ $timeout -eq 1 ]] && msg="Error 1: The device timed out\n"
    [[ $login_error -eq 1 ]] && msg="${msg}Error 2: Failed to login to device\n"
    [[ $sky_fall -eq 1 ]] && msg="${msg}Error 3: The sky is falling\n"

    { /usr/bin/nc <ip_of_my_sendmail_box> << EOF
mail from: server@domain.com
rcpt to: me@domain.com
data
to: me@domain.com
subject: Error during systems check
Content-Type: text/plain

$(printf "%b" "$msg")

Sent on: $(date)
.
quit
EOF
    } 1>/dev/null

}
```

Now, every thing here works as intended except that the newlines in `$msg` get seemingly stripped from my e-mail. If I wasn't e-mailing this text, then printf will happily interpret the newlines and show me two lines with text.

Let's say that an error 1 and an error 2 happened, I'll get this in my e-mail:

```
Error 1: The device timed outError 2: Failed to login to device
```

**Why no new line?**

If I change the `$msg` texts to have two `\n\n` characters at the end, like so:

```
[[ $timeout -eq 1 ]] && msg="Error 1: The device timed out\n\n"
[[ $login_error -eq 1 ]] && msg="${msg}Error 2: Failed to login to device\n\n"
```

then I get this in the e-mail:

```
Error 1: The device timed out

Error 2: Failed to login to device
```

**Notice the extra new line between them now.**

Does anyone know why I either get no newline or two newlines, but never the desired one newline.

Answer (score 3):

Try [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
msg=""
[[ $timeout     -eq 1 ]] && msg+=$'Error 1: The device timed out\n'
[[ $login_error -eq 1 ]] && msg+=$'Error 2: Failed to login to device\n'
[[ $sky_fall    -eq 1 ]] && msg+=$'Error 3: The sky is falling\n'
```

Comment: Funny, I was just reading about ANSI-C quoting when you posted this. Thanks for the info; I ended up using your block of code in my script.

Comment: I had meant to followup: with this I bet you don't need the `printf`: try just putting `$msg` in the here-doc.

Answer (score 1):

Your sub-shell is spitting out the newline but the heredoc expansion is dropping it as it is unquoted.

Try `printf %b $msg` in your shell to see the idea.

You need to use something like `printf %s\\n "$(printf %b "$msg")"` to get what you want.

Comment: Hmm... Doesn't seem to be working with the `printf %s\\n ...` bit of code. I'm pretty sure that I need to print/echo the `$msg` variable with a subshell because the netcat e-mail session doesn't interpret new line characters.

Comment: Doesn't work in what sense? What output are you getting? Did you include the quotes around the `$()` subshell? nc can't be the issue if you are getting newlines in the other parts of the heredoc output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies Glenn and Etan! However, I think I found the issue.

Turns out that the problem was more with Outlook (which I use to read the e-mails). It was stripping the line-breaks for those particular lines. I don't know why though.

[this post describes the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247546/outlook-autocleaning-my-line-breaks-and-screwing-up-my-email-format) I was seeing.

My fix, as recommended by that post, was to add `/t` character to the end of each `$msg` line. This tricked Outlook into not stripping the line-breaks.

I have no idea why other parts of my heredoc don't get their line-breaks stripped by Outlook. For example, I also `cat` a log file into the heredoc that's full of new lines, and that shows up fine. Oh well...

Edit: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks) also has good info on this behavior by Outlook.