# line break in SAS bulk generated email body

Tags: sas

I am trying to generate bulk emails through SAS, based on instructions of [this SUGI](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/038-2008.pdf) by Eric Tilanus.

I cannot put a line break and all the put statement products appear in the same line in the email body.

I am using SAS 9.4. Sample code is below.

Do you know how I can get a line break?

```
data _null_;
    length body $1024;
    set DSIN end=last;

file outbox;

    put '!EM_TO!' email;

    firstLine= catx(' ',"first line",put(dttm,datetime19.), "blah");
    put firstLine;

    /* how can I get a line break here? */

    put "second line";

    put '!EM_SEND!';
    put '!EM_NEWMSG!';
if last then put '!EM_ABORT!';
run;
```

Here is the email body generated:

```
first line 06JUL2015:21:25:40 blah second line
```

UPDATE: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247546/outlook-autocleaning-my-line-breaks-and-screwing-up-my-email-format) has useful info. Outlook truncates line breaks. Putting two spaces before the string bypasses Outlook's automatic line break truncation.

Comment: Isn't it just  something like "Extra line breaks were removed by Outlook" case?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the issue. Putting two spaces does the trick.

Comment: also you could use content_type="text/html" and put "<br>"; as workaround, if HTML-E-mail is an option in your process....