# newline in CakeEmail (Outlook)

Tags: email, cakephp, outlook, newline

I'm trying real hard to get a simple newline in an Email shown with Outlook which is sent with Cakephp's CakeEmail.

What I've tried so far:

- `<br/>`
- `"\n"`
- `"\n\n"` (this strangely works but I get not 1 but 2 newlines everything else won't work)
- `"\r\n"`
- `CakeEmail:emailFormat('text');` (with all of the above again, same result)

Any help would be appreciated. Been trying for an hour now. I'll bet those frakkin toasters got something to do with it.

Comment: Have you tried to figure whether the sent mail data reaches your mail server exactly as it has been sent? Because if that's the case, then this isn't related to CakePHP at all, but just an Outlook quirk. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247546/outlook-autocleaning-my-line-breaks-and-screwing-up-my-email-format** || **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks**

Comment: I have no idea why but suddenly it's working. Maybe the sysadmin did something to the exchange server. I didn't even restart my local machine. Going nuts here.

Comment: Just got the same problem again. Then i saw the small message: unneeded line breaks were removed.... never start something on a friday late afternoon.