# HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping, html-escape-characters

I’m using JavaScript to pull a value out from a hidden field and display it in a textbox. The value in the hidden field is encoded.

For example,

```html
<input id='hiddenId' type='hidden' value='chalk &amp; cheese' />
```

gets pulled into

```html
<input type='text' value='chalk &amp; cheese' />
```

via some jQuery to get the value from the hidden field (it’s at this point that I lose the encoding):

```js
$('#hiddenId').attr('value')
```

The problem is that when I read `chalk &amp; cheese` from the hidden field, JavaScript seems to lose the encoding. I do not want the value to be `chalk & cheese`. I want the literal `amp;` to be retained.

Is there a JavaScript library or a jQuery method that will HTML-encode a string?

Comment: Can you show the Javascript you are using?

Comment: have added how I get value from hidden field

Comment: http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb

Comment: Do NOT use the innerHTML method (the jQuery .html() method uses innerHTML), as on some (I've only tested Chrome) browsers, this won't escape quotes, so if you were to put your value into an attribute value, you would end up with an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: in what context is `chalk` and `cheese` ever used together 0_o

Comment: @d-_-b when comparing two items. example. they are as different as chalk and cheese ;)

Answer (score 1074, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer was posted a long ago, and the `htmlDecode` function introduced a XSS vulnerability. It has been modified changing the temporary element from a `div` to a `textarea` reducing the XSS chance. But nowadays, I would encourage you to use the DOMParser API as suggested in [other anwswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/5445).

---

I use these functions:

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  // Create a in-memory element, set its inner text (which is automatically encoded)
  // Then grab the encoded contents back out. The element never exists on the DOM.
  return $('<textarea/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<textarea/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Basically a textarea element is created in memory, but it is never appended to the document.

On the `htmlEncode` function I set the `innerText` of the element, and retrieve the encoded `innerHTML`; on the `htmlDecode` function I set the `innerHTML` value of the element and the `innerText` is retrieved.

Check a running example [here](http://jsbin.com/ejuru).

Comment: This works for most scenarios, but this implementation of htmlDecode will eliminate any extra whitespace.  So for some values of "input", input != htmlDecode(htmlEncode(input)).  This was a problem for us in some scenarios.

For example, if input = "<p>\t Hi \n There   </p>", a roundtrip encode/decode will yield "<p> Hi There </p>".  Most of the time this is okay, but sometimes it isn't. :)

Comment: Depends on the browser, on Firefox it is including the whitespaces, new lines... On IE it strips all.

Answer (score 565):

The jQuery trick doesn't encode quote marks and in IE it will strip your whitespace.

Based on the **escape** templatetag in Django, which I guess is heavily used/tested already, I made this function which does what's needed.

It's arguably simpler (and possibly faster) than any of the workarounds for the whitespace-stripping issue - and it encodes quote marks, which is essential if you're going to use the result inside an attribute value for example.

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return str
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

// I needed the opposite function today, so adding here too:
function htmlUnescape(str){
    return str
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
}
```

**Update 2013-06-17:**
In the search for the fastest escaping I have found this implementation of a `replaceAll` method:
http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg29#msg29
(also referenced here: [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string/6714233#6714233))
Some performance results here:
http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/25

It gives identical result string to the builtin `replace` chains above. I'd be very happy if someone could explain why it's faster!?

**Update 2015-03-04:**
I just noticed that AngularJS are using exactly the method above:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L435

They add a couple of refinements - they appear to be handling an [obscure Unicode issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points) as well as converting all non-alphanumeric characters to entities. I was under the impression the latter was not necessary as long as you have an UTF8 charset specified for your document.

I will note that (4 years later) Django still does not do either of these things, so I'm not sure how important they are:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8b1/django/utils/html.py#L44

**Update 2016-04-06:**
You may also wish to escape forward-slash `/`. This is not required for correct HTML encoding, however it is [recommended by OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) as an anti-XSS safety measure. (thanks to @JNF for suggesting this in comments)

```
        .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;');
```

Comment: @Ferruccio ...and for reasons why not to use &apos; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083754/why-shouldnt-apos-be-used-to-escape-single-quotes http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/03/19/apos-is-in-xml-in-html-use-39.aspx http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/07/01/the_curse_of_apos/

Answer (score 83):

Here's a non-jQuery version that is considerably faster than both the jQuery `.html()` version and the `.replace()` version. This preserves all whitespace, but like the jQuery version, doesn't handle quotes.

```js
function htmlEncode( html ) {
    return document.createElement( 'a' ).appendChild( 
        document.createTextNode( html ) ).parentNode.innerHTML;
};
```

**Speed:** http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/17

> [image: speed test]

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Script:

```js
function htmlEncode( html ) {
    return document.createElement( 'a' ).appendChild( 
        document.createTextNode( html ) ).parentNode.innerHTML;
};

function htmlDecode( html ) {
    var a = document.createElement( 'a' ); a.innerHTML = html;
    return a.textContent;
};

document.getElementById( 'text' ).value = htmlEncode( document.getElementById( 'hidden' ).value );

//sanity check
var html = '<div>   &amp; hello</div>';
document.getElementById( 'same' ).textContent = 
      'html === htmlDecode( htmlEncode( html ) ): ' 
    + ( html === htmlDecode( htmlEncode( html ) ) );
```

#### HTML:

```html
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="chalk    &amp; cheese" />
<input id="text" value="" />
<div id="same"></div>
```

Comment: This begs the question: why isn't it a global function in JS already?!

Answer (score 32):

I know this is an old one, but I wanted to post a variation of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/578288) that will work in IE without removing lines:

```js
function multiLineHtmlEncode(value) {
    var lines = value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = htmlEncode(lines[i]);
    }
    return lines.join('\r\n');
}

function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

Answer (score 29):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) provides [`_.escape()`](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) and [`_.unescape()`](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) methods that do this.

```
> _.unescape( "chalk &amp; cheese" );
  "chalk & cheese"

> _.escape( "chalk & cheese" );
  "chalk &amp; cheese"
```

Answer (score 12):

Good answer. Note that if the value to encode is `undefined` or `null` with jQuery 1.4.2 you might get errors such as:

`jQuery("<div/>").text(value).html is not a function`

OR

`Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'html'`

The solution is to modify the function to check for an actual value:

```
function htmlEncode(value){ 
    if (value) {
        return jQuery('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: `jQuery('<div/>').text(value || '').html()`

Answer (score 12):

For those who prefer plain javascript, here is the method I have used successfully:

```
function escapeHTML (str)
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode(str);
    div.appendChild(text);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, the encoding is not being lost.  The encoding is used by the markup parser (browser) during the page load.  Once the source is read and parsed and the browser has the DOM loaded into memory, the encoding has been parsed into what it represents. So by the time your JS is execute to read anything in memory, the char it gets is what the encoding represented.

I may be operating strictly on semantics here, but I wanted you to understand the purpose of encoding.  The word "lost" makes it sound like something isn't working like it should.

Answer (score 6):

Faster without Jquery. You can encode every character in your string:

```
function encode(e){return e.replace(/[^]/g,function(e){return"&#"+e.charCodeAt(0)+";"})}
```

Or just target the main characters to worry about (&, inebreaks, <, >, " and ') like:

```js
function encode(r){
return r.replace(/[\x26\x0A\<>'"]/g,function(r){return"&#"+r.charCodeAt(0)+";"})
}

test.value=encode('Encode HTML entities!\n\n"Safe" escape <script id=\'\'> & useful in <pre> tags!');

testing.innerHTML=test.value;

/*************
* \x26 is &ampersand (it has to be first),
* \x0A is newline,
*************/
```

```html
<textarea id=test rows="9" cols="55"></textarea>

<div id="testing">www.WHAK.com</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) has it built-in the [String class](http://prototypejs.org/api/string). So if you are using/plan to use Prototype, it does something like:

```
'<div class="article">This is an article</div>'.escapeHTML();
// -> "&lt;div class="article"&gt;This is an article&lt;/div&gt;"
```

Comment: After looking at Prototype's solution, this is all it's doing... `.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');`  Easy enough.

Comment: shouldn't it do something with quote marks too? that's not good

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple javascript solution. It extends String object with a method "HTMLEncode" which can be used on an object without parameter, or with a parameter.

```
String.prototype.HTMLEncode = function(str) {
  var result = "";
  var str = (arguments.length===1) ? str : this;
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
     var chrcode = str.charCodeAt(i);
     result+=(chrcode>128) ? "&#"+chrcode+";" : str.substr(i,1)
   }
   return result;
}
// TEST
console.log("stetaewteaw æø".HTMLEncode());
console.log("stetaewteaw æø".HTMLEncode("æåøåæå"))
```

I have made a [gist "HTMLEncode method for javascript"](https://gist.github.com/netsi1964/fcc8c0c6f1330d666372).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there isn't any straight forward HTML Encode/Decode method in javascript.

However, what you can do, is to use JS to create an arbitrary element, set its inner text, then read it using innerHTML.

Let's say, with jQuery, this should work:

```
var helper = $('chalk & cheese').hide().appendTo('body');
var htmled = helper.html();
helper.remove();
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: I find the downvote a little bit amusing, considering this answer is almost identical to the one that has over 870 upvotes, and was posted a little bit after this one.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [angular's sanitize](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L435)... (es6 module syntax)

```
// ref: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js
const SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP = /[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g;
const NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP = /([^\#-~| |!])/g;

const decodeElem = document.createElement('pre');


/**
 * Decodes html encoded text, so that the actual string may
 * be used.
 * @param value
 * @returns {string} decoded text
 */
export function decode(value) {
  if (!value) return '';
  decodeElem.innerHTML = value.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
  return decodeElem.textContent;
}


/**
 * Encodes all potentially dangerous characters, so that the
 * resulting string can be safely inserted into attribute or
 * element text.
 * @param value
 * @returns {string} encoded text
 */
export function encode(value) {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) return '';
  return String(value).
    replace(/&/g, '&amp;').
    replace(SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP, value => {
      var hi = value.charCodeAt(0);
      var low = value.charCodeAt(1);
      return '&#' + (((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000) + ';';
    }).
    replace(NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP, value => {
      return '&#' + value.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    }).
    replace(/</g, '&lt;').
    replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

export default {encode,decode};
```

Comment: While I do really like this answer and actually I think is a good approach I have a doubt, is the bitwise operator on `if (value === null | value === undefined) return '';` a typo or actually a feature? If so, why use that one and not the common `||` ? Thank you!!

Comment: @AlejandroVales I'm pretty sure it was a typo... corrected.

Comment: Well anyhow keep in mind that the | will lead to 0 or 1, so actually it did work ^^

Comment: couldn't you just use `== null`? `undefined` is the only thing to have equivalence with `null`, so two triple-equals aren't necessary anyway

Comment: that's not true at all. `null` and `0` are both falsy, yes, so you cant just do `!value`, but the whole point of `==` is to make certain things easier. `0 == null` is false. `undefined == null` is true. you can just do `value == null`

Answer (score 3):

My pure-JS function:

```
/**
 * HTML entities encode
 *
 * @param {string} str Input text
 * @return {string} Filtered text
 */
function htmlencode (str){

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
  return div.innerHTML;
}
```

> [JavaScript HTML Entities Encode & Decode](https://gist.github.com/yidas/797c9e6d5c856158cffd685b8a8b4ee4)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to escape/encode values in order to shuttle them from one input field to another.

```
<form>
 <input id="button" type="button" value="Click me">
 <input type="hidden" id="hiddenId" name="hiddenId" value="I like cheese">
 <input type="text" id="output" name="output">
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#button').click(function(e) {
            $('#output').val($('#hiddenId').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

JS doesn't go inserting raw HTML or anything; it just tells the DOM to set the `value` property (or attribute; not sure).  Either way, the DOM handles any encoding issues for you.  Unless you're doing something odd like using `document.write` or `eval`, HTML-encoding will be effectively transparent.

If you're talking about generating a new textbox to hold the result...it's still as easy.  Just pass the static part of the HTML to jQuery, and then set the rest of the properties/attributes on the object it returns to you.

```
$box = $('<input type="text" name="whatever">').val($('#hiddenId').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solve it using the function `encodeURIComponent` from JavaScript ([documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp))

For example, in your case if you use:

```
<input id='hiddenId' type='hidden' value='chalk & cheese' />
```

and

```
encodeURIComponent($('#hiddenId').attr('value'))
```

you will get `chalk%20%26%20cheese`. Even spaces are kept.

In my case, I had to encode one backslash and this code works perfectly

```
encodeURIComponent('name/surname')
```

and I got `name%2Fsurname`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little bit that emulates the `Server.HTMLEncode` function from Microsoft's ASP, written in pure JavaScript:

```js
function htmlEncode(s) {
  var ntable = {
    "&": "amp",
    "<": "lt",
    ">": "gt",
    "\"": "quot"
  };
  s = s.replace(/[&<>"]/g, function(ch) {
    return "&" + ntable[ch] + ";";
  })
  s = s.replace(/[^ -\x7e]/g, function(ch) {
    return "&#" + ch.charCodeAt(0).toString() + ";";
  });
  return s;
}
```

The result *does not* encode apostrophes, but encodes the other HTML specials and any character outside the 0x20-0x7e range.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery. I found this:

http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.htmlspecialchars

(part of jquery.string plugin offered by jQuery SDK)

The problem with Prototype I believe is that it extends base objects in JavaScript and will be incompatible with any jQuery you may have used. Of course, if you are already using Prototype and not jQuery, it won't be a problem.

EDIT: Also there is this, which is a port of Prototype's string utilities for jQuery:

http://stilldesigning.com/dotstring/

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlEnDeCode = (function() {
    var charToEntityRegex,
        entityToCharRegex,
        charToEntity,
        entityToChar;

    function resetCharacterEntities() {
        charToEntity = {};
        entityToChar = {};
        // add the default set
        addCharacterEntities({
            '&amp;'     :   '&',
            '&gt;'      :   '>',
            '&lt;'      :   '<',
            '&quot;'    :   '"',
            '&#39;'     :   "'"
        });
    }

    function addCharacterEntities(newEntities) {
        var charKeys = [],
            entityKeys = [],
            key, echar;
        for (key in newEntities) {
            echar = newEntities[key];
            entityToChar[key] = echar;
            charToEntity[echar] = key;
            charKeys.push(echar);
            entityKeys.push(key);
        }
        charToEntityRegex = new RegExp('(' + charKeys.join('|') + ')', 'g');
        entityToCharRegex = new RegExp('(' + entityKeys.join('|') + '|&#[0-9]{1,5};' + ')', 'g');
    }

    function htmlEncode(value){
        var htmlEncodeReplaceFn = function(match, capture) {
            return charToEntity[capture];
        };

        return (!value) ? value : String(value).replace(charToEntityRegex, htmlEncodeReplaceFn);
    }

    function htmlDecode(value) {
        var htmlDecodeReplaceFn = function(match, capture) {
            return (capture in entityToChar) ? entityToChar[capture] : String.fromCharCode(parseInt(capture.substr(2), 10));
        };

        return (!value) ? value : String(value).replace(entityToCharRegex, htmlDecodeReplaceFn);
    }

    resetCharacterEntities();

    return {
        htmlEncode: htmlEncode,
        htmlDecode: htmlDecode
    };
})();
```

This is from ExtJS source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
String.prototype.htmlEncode = function () {
    return String(this)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

}

var aString = '<script>alert("I hack your site")</script>';
console.log(aString.htmlEncode());
</script>
```

Will output: `&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;I hack your site&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;`

.htmlEncode() will be accessible on all strings once defined.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlEncodes the given value

```
  var htmlEncodeContainer = $('<div />');
  function htmlEncode(value) {
    if (value) {
      return htmlEncodeContainer.text(value).html();
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some issues with backslash in my Domain\User string.

I added this to the other escapes from Anentropic's answer

```
.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;')
```

Which I found here:
[How to escape backslash in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866461/how-to-escape-backslash-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Picking what `escapeHTML()` is doing in the prototype.js

Adding this script helps you escapeHTML:

```
String.prototype.escapeHTML = function() { 
    return this.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
}
```

now you can call escapeHTML method on strings in your script, like:

```
var escapedString = "<h1>this is HTML</h1>".escapeHTML();
// gives: "&lt;h1&gt;this is HTML&lt;/h1&gt;"
```

Hope it helps anyone looking for a simple solution without having to include the entire prototype.js

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the other answers here I made a version that replaces all the pertinent characters in one pass irrespective of the number of distinct encoded characters (only one call to `replace()`) so will be faster for larger strings.

It doesn't rely on the DOM API to exist or on other libraries.

```js
window.encodeHTML = (function() {
    function escapeRegex(s) {
        return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    }
    var encodings = {
        '&'  : '&amp;',
        '"'  : '&quot;',
        '\'' : '&#39;',
        '<'  : '&lt;',
        '>'  : '&gt;',
        '\\' : '&#x2F;'
    };
    function encode(what) { return encodings[what]; };
    var specialChars = new RegExp('[' +
        escapeRegex(Object.keys(encodings).join('')) +
    ']', 'g');

    return function(text) { return text.replace(specialChars, encode); };
})();
```

Having ran that once, you can now call

```js
encodeHTML('<>&"\'')
```

To get `&lt;&gt;&amp;&quot;&#39;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function encodeHTML(str) {
    return document.createElement("a").appendChild( 
        document.createTextNode(str)).parentNode.innerHTML;
};

function decodeHTML(str) {
    var element = document.createElement("a"); 
    element.innerHTML = str;
    return element.textContent;
};
var str = "<"
var enc = encodeHTML(str);
var dec = decodeHTML(enc);
console.log("str: " + str, "\nenc: " + enc, "\ndec: " + dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
There's certainly no jQuery required for that ! 
Here a JavaScript port from System.Web.HttpUtility (C# - disclaimer: not very tested):

```
"use strict";
function htmlDecode(s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;
    if (s.length == 0)
        return "";
    if (s.indexOf('&') == -1)
        return s;
    function isDigit(str) {
        return /^\d+$/.test(str);
    }
    function isHexDigit(str) {
        return /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g.test(str);
    }
    function initEntities() {
        var entities = {};
        entities["nbsp"] = '\u00A0';
        entities["iexcl"] = '\u00A1';
        entities["cent"] = '\u00A2';
        entities["pound"] = '\u00A3';
        entities["curren"] = '\u00A4';
        entities["yen"] = '\u00A5';
        entities["brvbar"] = '\u00A6';
        entities["sect"] = '\u00A7';
        entities["uml"] = '\u00A8';
        entities["copy"] = '\u00A9';
        entities["ordf"] = '\u00AA';
        entities["laquo"] = '\u00AB';
        entities["not"] = '\u00AC';
        entities["shy"] = '\u00AD';
        entities["reg"] = '\u00AE';
        entities["macr"] = '\u00AF';
        entities["deg"] = '\u00B0';
        entities["plusmn"] = '\u00B1';
        entities["sup2"] = '\u00B2';
        entities["sup3"] = '\u00B3';
        entities["acute"] = '\u00B4';
        entities["micro"] = '\u00B5';
        entities["para"] = '\u00B6';
        entities["middot"] = '\u00B7';
        entities["cedil"] = '\u00B8';
        entities["sup1"] = '\u00B9';
        entities["ordm"] = '\u00BA';
        entities["raquo"] = '\u00BB';
        entities["frac14"] = '\u00BC';
        entities["frac12"] = '\u00BD';
        entities["frac34"] = '\u00BE';
        entities["iquest"] = '\u00BF';
        entities["Agrave"] = '\u00C0';
        entities["Aacute"] = '\u00C1';
        entities["Acirc"] = '\u00C2';
        entities["Atilde"] = '\u00C3';
        entities["Auml"] = '\u00C4';
        entities["Aring"] = '\u00C5';
        entities["AElig"] = '\u00C6';
        entities["Ccedil"] = '\u00C7';
        entities["Egrave"] = '\u00C8';
        entities["Eacute"] = '\u00C9';
        entities["Ecirc"] = '\u00CA';
        entities["Euml"] = '\u00CB';
        entities["Igrave"] = '\u00CC';
        entities["Iacute"] = '\u00CD';
        entities["Icirc"] = '\u00CE';
        entities["Iuml"] = '\u00CF';
        entities["ETH"] = '\u00D0';
        entities["Ntilde"] = '\u00D1';
        entities["Ograve"] = '\u00D2';
        entities["Oacute"] = '\u00D3';
        entities["Ocirc"] = '\u00D4';
        entities["Otilde"] = '\u00D5';
        entities["Ouml"] = '\u00D6';
        entities["times"] = '\u00D7';
        entities["Oslash"] = '\u00D8';
        entities["Ugrave"] = '\u00D9';
        entities["Uacute"] = '\u00DA';
        entities["Ucirc"] = '\u00DB';
        entities["Uuml"] = '\u00DC';
        entities["Yacute"] = '\u00DD';
        entities["THORN"] = '\u00DE';
        entities["szlig"] = '\u00DF';
        entities["agrave"] = '\u00E0';
        entities["aacute"] = '\u00E1';
        entities["acirc"] = '\u00E2';
        entities["atilde"] = '\u00E3';
        entities["auml"] = '\u00E4';
        entities["aring"] = '\u00E5';
        entities["aelig"] = '\u00E6';
        entities["ccedil"] = '\u00E7';
        entities["egrave"] = '\u00E8';
        entities["eacute"] = '\u00E9';
        entities["ecirc"] = '\u00EA';
        entities["euml"] = '\u00EB';
        entities["igrave"] = '\u00EC';
        entities["iacute"] = '\u00ED';
        entities["icirc"] = '\u00EE';
        entities["iuml"] = '\u00EF';
        entities["eth"] = '\u00F0';
        entities["ntilde"] = '\u00F1';
        entities["ograve"] = '\u00F2';
        entities["oacute"] = '\u00F3';
        entities["ocirc"] = '\u00F4';
        entities["otilde"] = '\u00F5';
        entities["ouml"] = '\u00F6';
        entities["divide"] = '\u00F7';
        entities["oslash"] = '\u00F8';
        entities["ugrave"] = '\u00F9';
        entities["uacute"] = '\u00FA';
        entities["ucirc"] = '\u00FB';
        entities["uuml"] = '\u00FC';
        entities["yacute"] = '\u00FD';
        entities["thorn"] = '\u00FE';
        entities["yuml"] = '\u00FF';
        entities["fnof"] = '\u0192';
        entities["Alpha"] = '\u0391';
        entities["Beta"] = '\u0392';
        entities["Gamma"] = '\u0393';
        entities["Delta"] = '\u0394';
        entities["Epsilon"] = '\u0395';
        entities["Zeta"] = '\u0396';
        entities["Eta"] = '\u0397';
        entities["Theta"] = '\u0398';
        entities["Iota"] = '\u0399';
        entities["Kappa"] = '\u039A';
        entities["Lambda"] = '\u039B';
        entities["Mu"] = '\u039C';
        entities["Nu"] = '\u039D';
        entities["Xi"] = '\u039E';
        entities["Omicron"] = '\u039F';
        entities["Pi"] = '\u03A0';
        entities["Rho"] = '\u03A1';
        entities["Sigma"] = '\u03A3';
        entities["Tau"] = '\u03A4';
        entities["Upsilon"] = '\u03A5';
        entities["Phi"] = '\u03A6';
        entities["Chi"] = '\u03A7';
        entities["Psi"] = '\u03A8';
        entities["Omega"] = '\u03A9';
        entities["alpha"] = '\u03B1';
        entities["beta"] = '\u03B2';
        entities["gamma"] = '\u03B3';
        entities["delta"] = '\u03B4';
        entities["epsilon"] = '\u03B5';
        entities["zeta"] = '\u03B6';
        entities["eta"] = '\u03B7';
        entities["theta"] = '\u03B8';
        entities["iota"] = '\u03B9';
        entities["kappa"] = '\u03BA';
        entities["lambda"] = '\u03BB';
        entities["mu"] = '\u03BC';
        entities["nu"] = '\u03BD';
        entities["xi"] = '\u03BE';
        entities["omicron"] = '\u03BF';
        entities["pi"] = '\u03C0';
        entities["rho"] = '\u03C1';
        entities["sigmaf"] = '\u03C2';
        entities["sigma"] = '\u03C3';
        entities["tau"] = '\u03C4';
        entities["upsilon"] = '\u03C5';
        entities["phi"] = '\u03C6';
        entities["chi"] = '\u03C7';
        entities["psi"] = '\u03C8';
        entities["omega"] = '\u03C9';
        entities["thetasym"] = '\u03D1';
        entities["upsih"] = '\u03D2';
        entities["piv"] = '\u03D6';
        entities["bull"] = '\u2022';
        entities["hellip"] = '\u2026';
        entities["prime"] = '\u2032';
        entities["Prime"] = '\u2033';
        entities["oline"] = '\u203E';
        entities["frasl"] = '\u2044';
        entities["weierp"] = '\u2118';
        entities["image"] = '\u2111';
        entities["real"] = '\u211C';
        entities["trade"] = '\u2122';
        entities["alefsym"] = '\u2135';
        entities["larr"] = '\u2190';
        entities["uarr"] = '\u2191';
        entities["rarr"] = '\u2192';
        entities["darr"] = '\u2193';
        entities["harr"] = '\u2194';
        entities["crarr"] = '\u21B5';
        entities["lArr"] = '\u21D0';
        entities["uArr"] = '\u21D1';
        entities["rArr"] = '\u21D2';
        entities["dArr"] = '\u21D3';
        entities["hArr"] = '\u21D4';
        entities["forall"] = '\u2200';
        entities["part"] = '\u2202';
        entities["exist"] = '\u2203';
        entities["empty"] = '\u2205';
        entities["nabla"] = '\u2207';
        entities["isin"] = '\u2208';
        entities["notin"] = '\u2209';
        entities["ni"] = '\u220B';
        entities["prod"] = '\u220F';
        entities["sum"] = '\u2211';
        entities["minus"] = '\u2212';
        entities["lowast"] = '\u2217';
        entities["radic"] = '\u221A';
        entities["prop"] = '\u221D';
        entities["infin"] = '\u221E';
        entities["ang"] = '\u2220';
        entities["and"] = '\u2227';
        entities["or"] = '\u2228';
        entities["cap"] = '\u2229';
        entities["cup"] = '\u222A';
        entities["int"] = '\u222B';
        entities["there4"] = '\u2234';
        entities["sim"] = '\u223C';
        entities["cong"] = '\u2245';
        entities["asymp"] = '\u2248';
        entities["ne"] = '\u2260';
        entities["equiv"] = '\u2261';
        entities["le"] = '\u2264';
        entities["ge"] = '\u2265';
        entities["sub"] = '\u2282';
        entities["sup"] = '\u2283';
        entities["nsub"] = '\u2284';
        entities["sube"] = '\u2286';
        entities["supe"] = '\u2287';
        entities["oplus"] = '\u2295';
        entities["otimes"] = '\u2297';
        entities["perp"] = '\u22A5';
        entities["sdot"] = '\u22C5';
        entities["lceil"] = '\u2308';
        entities["rceil"] = '\u2309';
        entities["lfloor"] = '\u230A';
        entities["rfloor"] = '\u230B';
        entities["lang"] = '\u2329';
        entities["rang"] = '\u232A';
        entities["loz"] = '\u25CA';
        entities["spades"] = '\u2660';
        entities["clubs"] = '\u2663';
        entities["hearts"] = '\u2665';
        entities["diams"] = '\u2666';
        entities["quot"] = '\u0022';
        entities["amp"] = '\u0026';
        entities["lt"] = '\u003C';
        entities["gt"] = '\u003E';
        entities["OElig"] = '\u0152';
        entities["oelig"] = '\u0153';
        entities["Scaron"] = '\u0160';
        entities["scaron"] = '\u0161';
        entities["Yuml"] = '\u0178';
        entities["circ"] = '\u02C6';
        entities["tilde"] = '\u02DC';
        entities["ensp"] = '\u2002';
        entities["emsp"] = '\u2003';
        entities["thinsp"] = '\u2009';
        entities["zwnj"] = '\u200C';
        entities["zwj"] = '\u200D';
        entities["lrm"] = '\u200E';
        entities["rlm"] = '\u200F';
        entities["ndash"] = '\u2013';
        entities["mdash"] = '\u2014';
        entities["lsquo"] = '\u2018';
        entities["rsquo"] = '\u2019';
        entities["sbquo"] = '\u201A';
        entities["ldquo"] = '\u201C';
        entities["rdquo"] = '\u201D';
        entities["bdquo"] = '\u201E';
        entities["dagger"] = '\u2020';
        entities["Dagger"] = '\u2021';
        entities["permil"] = '\u2030';
        entities["lsaquo"] = '\u2039';
        entities["rsaquo"] = '\u203A';
        entities["euro"] = '\u20AC';
        return entities;
    }
    var Entities = initEntities();
    var rawEntity = [];
    var entity = [];
    var output = [];
    var len = s.length;
    var state = 0;
    var number = 0;
    var is_hex_value = false;
    var have_trailing_digits = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var c = s[i];
        if (state == 0) {
            if (c == '&') {
                entity.push(c);
                rawEntity.push(c);
                state = 1;
            }
            else {
                output.push(c);
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (c == '&') {
            state = 1;
            if (have_trailing_digits) {
                entity.push(number.toString());
                have_trailing_digits = false;
            }
            output.push(entity.join(""));
            entity = [];
            entity.push('&');
            continue;
        }
        if (state == 1) {
            if (c == ';') {
                state = 0;
                output.push(entity.join(""));
                output.push(c);
                entity = [];
            }
            else {
                number = 0;
                is_hex_value = false;
                if (c != '#') {
                    state = 2;
                }
                else {
                    state = 3;
                }
                entity.push(c);
                rawEntity.push(c);
            }
        }
        else if (state == 2) {
            entity.push(c);
            if (c == ';') {
                var key = entity.join("");
                if (key.length > 1 && Entities.hasOwnProperty(key.substr(1, key.length - 2)))
                    key = Entities[key.substr(1, key.length - 2)].toString();
                output.push(key);
                state = 0;
                entity = [];
                rawEntity = [];
            }
        }
        else if (state == 3) {
            if (c == ';') {
                if (number == 0)
                    output.push(rawEntity.join("") + ";");
                else if (number > 65535) {
                    output.push("&#");
                    output.push(number.toString());
                    output.push(";");
                }
                else {
                    output.push(String.fromCharCode(number));
                }
                state = 0;
                entity = [];
                rawEntity = [];
                have_trailing_digits = false;
            }
            else if (is_hex_value && isHexDigit(c)) {
                number = number * 16 + parseInt(c, 16);
                have_trailing_digits = true;
                rawEntity.push(c);
            }
            else if (isDigit(c)) {
                number = number * 10 + (c.charCodeAt(0) - '0'.charCodeAt(0));
                have_trailing_digits = true;
                rawEntity.push(c);
            }
            else if (number == 0 && (c == 'x' || c == 'X')) {
                is_hex_value = true;
                rawEntity.push(c);
            }
            else {
                state = 2;
                if (have_trailing_digits) {
                    entity.push(number.toString());
                    have_trailing_digits = false;
                }
                entity.push(c);
            }
        }
    }
    if (entity.length > 0) {
        output.push(entity.join(""));
    }
    else if (have_trailing_digits) {
        output.push(number.toString());
    }
    return output.join("");
}
function htmlEncode(s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;
    if (s.length == 0)
        return s;
    var needEncode = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var c = s[i];
        if (c == '&' || c == '"' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c.charCodeAt(0) > 159
            || c == '\'') {
            needEncode = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!needEncode)
        return s;
    var output = [];
    var len = s.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var ch = s[i];
        switch (ch) {
            case '&':
                output.push("&amp;");
                break;
            case '>':
                output.push("&gt;");
                break;
            case '<':
                output.push("&lt;");
                break;
            case '"':
                output.push("&quot;");
                break;
            case '\'':
                output.push("&#39;");
                break;
            case '\uff1c':
                output.push("&#65308;");
                break;
            case '\uff1e':
                output.push("&#65310;");
                break;
            default:
                if (ch.charCodeAt(0) > 159 && ch.charCodeAt(0) < 256) {
                    output.push("&#");
                    output.push(ch.charCodeAt(0).toString());
                    output.push(";");
                }
                else
                    output.push(ch);
                break;
        }
    }
    return output.join("");
}
```