# newline in Rackspace Cron Job email

Tags: asp.net, email, logging, outlook, rackspace

I'm running backups against multiple databases hosted at Rackspace. This is working fine. The problem I'm running into is with the results email. I'm using Response.Write to write a message to the web page which is used for logging and is also consumed by the results mail sent out by the job. The problem is I can't seem to get newlines to appear between log messages. The logfile stored on the server is correct, but only the first newline shows up in the email.
The mail is in Plain Text format so I tried using "\n" and System.Environment.Newline and neither work. I also tried using `<br/>` with no luck.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Outlook being clever and removing 'extra' line breaks.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks) appears to provide a solution to force Outlook to display the line breaks. Use `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.