# How to formatting a text with SimpleMailMessage?

Tags: java, spring, email, velocity

My email content text is

```
String text = "Hey, You are create a new Account! Best, MyTeam";
```

How can I format the text to:

```
Hey,

You are create a new Account!

Best, MyTeam
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleMailMessage` can only handle plain-text messages, so you need to embed explicit line-breaks in your String:

```
String text = "Hey,\n\nYou are create a new Account!\n\nBest, MyTeam";
```

A templating system such as velocity or freemarker may make this easier.

If you want to handle HTML messages, you need to use `JavaMailSender` and `MimeMessagePreparator`.

Comment: Microsoft Outlook removes extra line breaks so if you are using Outlook, the above approach might not work perfectly. In that case you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String text = "Hey, You are create a new Account!/n Best, MyTeam";
```

or this(if that has to be inside some HTML page)

```
String text = "Hey, You are create a new Account!<br/> Best, MyTeam";
```

or

```
String text = "Hey, You are create a new Account!" +System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Regards, MyTeam";
```

Comment: It's not work. I get "Hey, You are create a new Account!<br/> Best, MyTeam"

Comment: Show a bit more information about it. Where is that variable being called? Have you try with the line separator?

Comment: @sfrj Using System.getProperty("line.separator")  it doesn't seem to work but if you add \n directly it works fine. Did you tested the third approach as it doesn't seem to be working for me.Thanks

Comment: Just  figured that outlook was removing the extra line breaks. It seems to be working fine.