# Formatting Emails sent from SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wish to format my messages sent from my API to look a bit more proper. I'm wondering what the best practice for this is?

**EmailController**, this is where i send my messages.

```
    @PostMapping("/send")
    public void sendEmail(@RequestBody Contact contact) throws Exception {
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            mailMessage.setTo("test@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.setSubject(contact.getSubject());
            mailMessage.setText("Email: " + contact.getEmail() +
                                            contact.getMessage());
          try {
            emailSenderService.sendEmail(mailMessage);
        } catch (MailException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The format looks quite ugly, is there any way i can make the text bold and add linebreakers etc ?
any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: did you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484468/4373948  ?

Comment: also you can read this to understand how to format your message :  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> format my messages [...] to look a bit more proper

That sounds like you want rich text, where you can change font size, bold the text, change color, etc.

For that, you want your email to be **HTML**, not plain text.

To generate HTML, it's usually best to use a Template Engine. Spring Boot have a [choice of multiple Template Engines](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines) for building your HTML web pages, so you might as well use the same Template Engine for building the email text, e.g. Thymeleaf.

So find a tutorial on how to invoke Thymeleaf, and capture the rendered HTML in a String. Then give that string to `mailMessage.setText(...)`.