# HTML/CSS - Best practice for preserving white space on certain elements?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

What is the *best* way to preserve white space in HTML?  We have a lot of pages that bring down data from our database, and the data may have multiple spaces in it.  The rendered HTML elements that hold the data vary from anchor tags `(<a>), spans (<span>), table rows (<tr>, <td>, etc.`

The easiest thing to do right now would be to add a global css class like so:

```
body a, span, tr, td { white-space: pre; }
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to implement this *without* assigning a class to each individual HTML element.

Comment: Your example does not use a css class and does not require you to assign a class to each individual element.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir Yea, I rarely deal with CSS, don't know CSS very well lol

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I would use the same technique, but inside a data class wrapper where it is needed:

```
.data a, .data span, .data tr, .data td { white-space: pre; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="data">
....

</div>
```

Comment: This is a good idea.  It's far easier to wrap the output, than change all the tags in that output.

Answer (score 40):

```
<pre>no need for       style</pre>
```

Comment: Be aware that the `pre` tag is usually displayed as a `block` element.

Comment: Also be aware that `pre` usually (always?) includes `font-family: monospace;` in its default style.

Comment: For many people, this is not a helpful answer because much of the time it's better to have your tags correspond to the UI element they are making, and this is better for SEO.  For example, do not ever put your headers in <pre>.  Instead, use <h1>, <h2>, etc.

Answer (score 14):

This depends on whether you wish to preserve *all* whitespace in certain elements and what exactly should happen there. Assuming that there are no CSS rules that might interfere, your CSS can be simplified to

```
a, span, tr { white-space: pre; }
```

because an `a` element is alway within `body` and `td` by default inherits the property from `tr`.

If you only wish to prevent multiple spaces from collapsing, instead of forcing fixed division to lines, then `white-space: pre-wrap` or replacing spaces by no-break spaces might be more adequate.

Finally, the need and possibilities for restricting the rule to selected elements greatly depend on how the selection should be done. Perhaps you can selectively set `white-space` to `pre` (or `pre-wrap`) to some elements that enclose the relevant parts, remembering that the property inherits if not set on inner elements.

You can also break the inheritance: you could set `white-space: pre` on a `table` element for example, if you wish to make the rule apply to *most* of the content, and set `white-space: normal` on those rows or cells where it is not to be applied.

Answer (score 11):

What is wrong with replacing spaces by &nbsp;? This should work inside any element and preserve the spaces in the rendered output.

Comment: The wrong with this is that there are 26 different whitespaces (`\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x20\xA0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000\u2028\u2029\uFEFF`) (http://perfectionkills.com/whitespace-deviations/ lists 25, but there is also `\uFEFF`) and the width of "white-space" is not the same in all of possible white-spaces. It's up to font designer to decide the width of character, also white-space character. If you replace space (`\x20`) with &nbsp;, it should be okay, but there are 25 other possible white-spaces to care of.

Comment: Depending on your server side language, you may have something like char.iswhitespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx which makes it easy to replace all whitespace characters.

Comment: However, using the whitespace: pre option has been simpler/easier in my opinion as you can change the stylesheet without changing your code.

Comment: HTML5 spec says that browsers should only collapse 5 (ascii) whitespace characters (space, tab, cr, lf, ff). The unicode ones don't collapse, at least not on modern browsers. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#skip-whitespace

Comment: The main issue about `&nbsp;` is that it's non-breaking which breaks the responsive design when the size changes.