# Preserving white space in an HTML select option without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Requirement:**

I need to preserve white space in a response i receive from backend, use the response as input for select dropdown in my UI and need to send the user selection to backend again.

**Problem:**

The white-space css property didn't worked for me. Though replacing spaces with **&nbsp** worked, i can't use that solution, Since the input i receive is large and replacing all spaces with **&nbsp** requires lot of computation. There were other framework issues too.

**Question:**

Is there any other solution to preserve white spaces in an HTML select option other than javascript way of using **&nbsp?**

Comment: I believe that this will help you

[stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements

Comment: I dont think there is any solution other than using `&nbsp;`

Comment: @Paulo Lima - I tried White-space: pre and White-space: pre-wrap with an example before. Somehow the white-space property is not working for select. I am not sure why

Comment: @Shankar white-space will not work for select

Comment: @Paulo Lima - Please find the JS Fiddle below http://jsfiddle.net/sankarpeddi/EuVQ2/

Comment: I'm sorry for what I see is only via javascript yourself, because the option does not let the css seems to act

Answer (score -1):

did you try wrapping it in `<pre></pre>` tags?

Comment: You mean like <option><pre>New York</pre></option>?.. I can't use it that way since i am using Ember.select

Comment: seriously your're gonna down vote me even though you never mentioned you use ember and I just took my time to help... not cool
anyway if you need the whitespaces only for the submitted data, not for the frontend, try saving the string in javascript and posting it on submit

Comment: I did not down voted you. I am sorry if it was a mistake. I tried to upvote but i didn't have sufficient points. I do respect you for taking time to help others.

Comment: May be it will work to save the string and sending it to submit than sending user selection. Let me give it a try. Thanks for the help!