# Replacing &nbsp; with something better

Tags: html

I have the following code.

I am trying to replace the user of 4 &nbsp:

```
   <p>First: 10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Second: 21&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Third:31&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</p>
```

I tried the following:

```
    <span class='spanspc'>
```

CSS:

```
    .spanSpacing {
        margin-left:30px;   
      }
```

Comment: Use CSS to handle styling

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS - Best practice for preserving white space on certain elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this line of html, you can use `<pre>` tag

like

```html
<pre>First: 10    Second: 21    Third:31  </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<span>`s aren't respecting the margin because they're set to `display: inline` by default. You could set them to `display: inline-block` for an easy fix:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>First: 20</span>
  <span>Second: 21</span>
  <span>Third: 31</span>
</p>
```

If you're working with data, you should consider using a `<table>`:

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First: 10</td>
    <td>Second: 21</td>
    <td>Third: 31</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

If the information is more of a list, use `<ul>` or `<ol>`:

```css
ol {
  padding: 0;
}
ol > li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 2em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First: 20</li>
  <li>Second: 21</li>
  <li>Third: 31</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a `pre` as already mentioned, nor use CSS styling, `&nbsp;` is your best option, you can however make it slightly cleaner by making every other one an actual space.

```
<p>First: 10&nbsp; &nbsp; Second:21 &nbsp; &nbsp;Third:31 &nbsp; &nbsp</p>
```