# How can I accept the data from database which has new lines and 'n' number of spaces in it?

Tags: html, mysql

I have a database , which has a "data" column with "TEXT" data type. So I want to fetch that row having data with new lines(like I like 
cooking) and also number of spaces ( like I'm       cooking).  I get the output as I like cooking ....and ... I'm cooking. I know the html neglects the blankspaces and  newline characters and we need to use &nbsp for it... But when the data is enormous , applying &nbsp can be cumbersome. Can any one suggest any method to solve it ? I'd be very thankful to ur answers..

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS - Best practice for preserving white space on certain elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements)

Comment: Yup That worked ;) (y) Thank you Mr.David..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `white-space: pre` for elements that need. And your HTML code should be in the certain box with a ID name, something like this:

```
<div id='test'>
// anything
<div>
```

then for CSS: // table and link

```
#test tr, #test a{white-space: pre;}
```