# GWT: How to prevent leading/trailing whitespace being removed in InlineLabel?

Tags: java, html, gwt

I have a line of text that contains multiple span elements. Example:

```
<div class="line">
    <span class="username">mario_sunny: </span><span class="message">Hello would you like to buy a <span class="item">Match</span>?</span>
</div>
```

The problem is when I try to create this in Java using GWT's [InlineLabel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineLabel.html) or [InlineHTML](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineHTML.html), it trims the leading/trailing spaces within the span, as you can see here:

[image]

How do I prevent this?

Here is my code:

```
HorizontalPanel lineLabel = new HorizontalPanel();
InlineHTML usernameLabel = new InlineHTML();
InlineLabel messageLabel = new InlineLabel();

lineLabel.setStyleName("chat-line");

usernameLabel.setStyleName("chat-username");
usernameLabel.setText("mario_sunny: ");

messageLabel.setText("Hello would you like to buy a Match?");

lineLabel.add(usernameLabel);
lineLabel.add(messageLabel);
```

Comment: See this: [HTML/CSS - Best practice for preserving white space on certain elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements)

Comment: It's GWT that is removing the whitespace, not HTML. On pure HTML the whitespace renders fine. But GWT removes it. I want to use GWT but also preserve the whitespace.

Comment: In GWT 2.7 that I use, the space is still present in the output markup. `white-space: pre;` makes it clearly visible. Also changing `HorizontalPanel` (rendered as `<table>`) to `FlowPanel` (rendered as `<div>`) helps, but I don't know if that would be acceptable.

Comment: Oh. I assumed it was GWT. I will try that. Thanks.