# Flask Python, Why Text Formatting Doesn't Work

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, text-formatting

[image]

```
row1 = ["Date: "  + date,  "Price:"     + price]
row2 = ["Name: "  + name,  "Quantity: " + quantity]
row3 = ["Title: " + title, "Owned: "    + owned]
row4 = ["Type: "  + type,  "Value: "    + value]

output_text = output_text + "\n" + \
              ('{:30s} {:20s}'.format(row1[0], row1[1])) + "\n" + \
              ('{:30s} {:20s}'.format(row2[0], row2[1])) + "\n" + \
              ('{:30s} {:20s}'.format(row3[0], row3[1])) + "\n" + \
              ('{:30s} {:20s}'.format(row4[0], row4[1])) + "\n"

print(output_text)
```

So, printing it to the console shows that the formatting is good, but when seeing it on the localhost website, the formatting seems to have no effect.
What's the best way to align two columns of text and have it stick on the Flask page?

Thanks

Comment: Console has monospaced font, but your page does not.

Comment: You can wrap it between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags but it is better to spit out proper HTML instead and use a `<table>` for tabular data.

Comment: Browser will merge multiple consecutive blank spaces, you have to use `<pre>` tag as @Selcuk said or use css for doing so, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements

Comment: @Selcuk yup, <pre> tags solved this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<pre>` `</pre>` tags solved this formatting issue.