# How do I indent an html page with "TAB" (or four space characters)?

Tags: html, css

I want to embed my C code in the HTML page, but the HTML format will only keep the text to the left. As follows:

#### HTML

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .codebox {
            color: rgb(230, 230, 210);

            width: 700px;
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;

            background-color: rgb(170, 150, 190, 0.37);
            border: 2px solid rgb(170, 150, 190);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
</style>

<div class="codebox">
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        size_t x;
        for(x = 0; x < 256; ++x) {
            ...
        }
        return 0;
    }
</div>
```

#### But the actual effect is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
size_t x;
for(x = 0; x < 256; ++x) {
...
}
return 0;
}
```

I know can use the "pre" tag, but this will make all the formats be rendered.

I am not familiar with the knowledge of the web front end. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML/CSS - Best practice for preserving white space on certain elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994516/html-css-best-practice-for-preserving-white-space-on-certain-elements)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "but this will make all the formats be rendered." thats what the `pre` tag is for...

Comment: For example, a text contained in the pre tag has four space characters at the beginning of each line. However, in HTML code, because the code indent is controlled to make the code more readable when writing, the indent of the content in the pre tag is not four space characters when it is displayed in the actual web page.

Comment: In the link you just gave me, I tried "white space: pre", so I got the same effect as the pre tag.

Comment: That is, extra space indents appear.

Comment: [As shown in the figure](https://sngrotesque.com/downloads/stackoverflow_01.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `pre` (= pre-formated code)
2 ways =>
a) use the tag `<pre>`
b) use the css `white-space : pre-wrap;`

but the `pre` directive is not enough  because you have a `<` charater in your text.
another 2 ways =>
a) change all yours `<` characters into `&lt;` html entities
b) use a `<code>` tag.

sample:

```css
.codebox {

  white-space      : pre-wrap;

  color            : darkblue;
  width            : 400px;
/*  height           : 100%; */
  padding-top      : 2px;
  padding-left     : 5px;
  padding-right    : 5px;
  padding-bottom   : 2px;
  background-color : rgb(170, 150, 190, 0.37);
  border           : 2px solid rgb(170, 150, 190);
  border-radius    : 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="codebox"><code>
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      size_t x;
      for(x = 0; x < 256; ++x) {
          ...
      }
      return 0;
    }
</code></div>
```

All in one...

```css
code {
  display           : block;
  white-space       : pre-wrap;
  background        : #f5f5f5;
  tab-width         : 4;      /* may help */
  overflow-x        : auto;   /* may help */
  color             : darkblue;
  width             : 400px;
  padding           : 0 1em;
  background-color  : rgb(170, 150, 190, 0.37);
  border            : 2px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius     : 5px;
  }
code::after {
  content : '\A'
  }
```

```html
<code>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  size_t x;
  for(x = 0; x < 256; ++x) 
    {
    ...
    }
  return 0;
  }
</code>
```

Comment: [This is my web front-end page code](https:///sngrotesque.com/misc/stackoverflow_02.png)

Comment: [This is the actual situation](https://sngrotesque.com/misc/stackoverflow_03.png)

Comment: I did as you said, but the indentation in the HTML code still exists in the actual page. Is there any way to make the page ignore the extra code indentation in the HTML? thank you

Comment: @SN-Grotesque no, it is the principle of the `pre` command, and it is not variable geometry.
but if you consider my answer completely useless, I can delete it.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I need to learn more about web front-end code.