# How to add line breaks through java and outlook should accept line breaks

Tags: java

I have a program in which I am sending the mail and my mail body is contains the following content..

```
abcParameters.put(defConstants.REPORT_MESSAGE, "Invalid file sent by tt. Hence ffgghh  was unable
                  to process it : " + s+ "\n" +e.getMessage().toString());
```

Now the issue is that outlook does not accept line breaks but I need line breaks afte the customised message and exception message so please advise how to achieve this

Comment: have you tried `"\r\n"` ?

Comment: It's probably sending mail as HTML. Try `"<br />"` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks similiar question (Answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\CarriageReturn\LineFeed aka `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.asciitable.com/) must be helpful for you. try "%0A" instead of "\n". The real source is [here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/48885)

You need to add "%0A" where ever you need a new line in your code. In your case

```
 abcParameters.put(defConstants.REPORT_MESSAGE, "Invalid file sent by tt. Hence ffgghh  was unable
              to process it : " + s+ "%0A" +e.getMessage().toString());
```

Comment: @who downvoted: i have posted this solution only after trying myself. [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/48885) the proof. Thanks anyway.