# Newlines in Outlook 365 e-mail sent from Play Java

Tags: java, html, email, playframework, outlook

When I try sending the below note using Play framework's e-mail utility as "text/html", the new line is not being preserved

```
     **Original string**
     this is a test
     this is a test
```

But what I see in my e-mail is the newline linebreaks being abandoned somewhere either in Outlook or in Java

```
     **Result**
     this is a test this is a test
```

I've tried all of the suggestion from below by adding br,\n, \r\n, \t\t,  etc to my program and still cannot get the new lines to display properly

[How do I format a String in an email so Outlook will print the line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is HTML, line break is the `<br>` HTML element.

Comment: I've tried <br> and it is not working. The e-mail prints the <br> in the message

Comment: Then you are not sending as text/html. Is the whole thing a well formed HTML with the html and body tags?

Comment: that is a very good suggestion. on closer inspection I am going out as this is a test &amp;lt;br&amp;gt this is a test &amp;lt;br&amp;gt

Comment: Thanks for remind about the well formatted HTML. That was my problem.